# Context parameter in onReceive() method is deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated

[image]
I use this reciever in my app. recently I noticed this problem 
what is the solution to avoid this deprecated

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    sendNotification(context,1,intent);
    sendNotification(context,2,intent);
}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Can you paste the deprecation error here

Comment: I added  image link for deprecated code because deprecated doesn't appear by copy and paste

Comment: Add @NonNull and see if that helps

Comment: I added it but didn't affect